# Take the values of an array and make them the indexes of another array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I make the values of an array the index of another array?  I am trying to count the different integers that were entered.  When I run the code, I am getting an index out of bounds message.  Any thoughts?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatchineNums{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int[] arr = new int[4];
      System.out.print("Enter 4 numbers: ");
      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
         arr[i] = input.nextInt();
      }

      int[] count = new int[arr.length];
      for(int i = count.length; i > -1; i--){
         int value = arr[i];
         count[value]++; //I think my problem is here but can't figure out why.  

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If they enter a number 4 or greater you will get out of bounds error

Comment: Please always include the full error message. It contains useful information like the exact line where the error gets thrown and the exact reason (for example the value of the index that was out of bound).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting index out of bounds exception because you're out-of-bound.

You need to start your loop from `count.length - 1`, not from `count.length`.

```
for (int i = count.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {...}
```

> How can I make the values of an array the index of another array?

You cannot *make indices*. You can create an array big enough to have all the indices you need. Just keep the maximum value of your inputs and then create an array this size. Then you have an array with all these indices.

A better way to handle this problem is to use a hashmap. The keys will be the inputs and the values will be the counter of each of them. This way is better than an array because you have a map entry for each different input and that's it. Using an array you'll end up having a really sparse array with many "holes".

Comment: Hashmap is a relatively complex data structure, you should consider his probable level as a beginner or new programmer, and make more useful suggestions based on said level.

Comment: The problem can still be solved with an array, there's really no need for a hashmap. But I still acknowledge that your suggestion is much more useful. Thanks.

Comment: @KrishnanshuGupta Hashmap is a very basic data structure and a super common one. A beginner (and honestly anyone else) should want to improve their skills and knowledge and to use the right methods to solve problems. An array is a bad one here. Think about these inputs: 2, 17, 100000, 100000. What will be the size of the array and how much of it will be used?

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I just feel like for a person who is having this sort of basic trouble, more practice with basic programming like looping and arrays are more useful than going to the OOP part of Java and using hashmap. In my case, I learned hashmaps, trees, and linklist, after arrays and arraylist. But it took me about 4-5 months to get to that point.

Comment: Hello - I definitely agree with both of you.  I failed to mention that I was just introduced to arrays and for loops 3 days ago.  SHG - I do understand what you are saying about giant holes  in the length of the array especially if the user enters a large value.  The problem I am working is from a practice mid term and I was thinking that an array and for loop would be the best tools to use based on what we have been taught so far.

Comment: You're right @bigpunz04, just use the tools you have learned so far for your tests, as sometimes teachers take off points for using techniques not taught in class [personal experience ;( ], but I think you should try to expand your understanding or arrays and java itself.  There are tons of different tutorials online and they will probably be very helpful to you. You don't have to necessarily use hashmap, though. Good luck!